# The integer linear programming(ILP) function in CVXOPT returns non integers

Tags: python-2.7, linear-programming, glpk, cvxopt

I wanted to optimize a function using ILP implementing by CVXOPT , GLPK in python. I wrote this code, but it gives me non integer solution especially 0.5. Could anyone help me?

```
    import math
    import numpy as np
    import cvxopt
    from cvxopt import glpk
    from cvxopt import matrix


    G = np.array([
     [-1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  1., -1.,  0.,  1., 1.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1., -1.,  0.,  1., -1.,  0.,  1., -1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1., 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  1., -1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0., -1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1., -1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0., 0., -1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1., -1., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 1.,  1., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1., -1., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 1.,  1., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

    h = np.array([[ 0.], [ 0.], [ 0.], [ 0.], [ 0.], [ 0.], [ 0.], [ 0.], [ 0.], [ 0.], [ 0.], [ 0.], [ 0.], [ 0.], [ 0.], [ 1.], [ 1.], [ 1.], [ 1.], [ 1.], [ 1.], [ 1.], [ 1.], [ 1.], [ 1.], [ 1.], [ 1.], [ 1.], [ 1.], [ 1.], [ 0.], [ 0.], [ 1.], [ 1.], [ 0.], [ 1.], [ 1.], [ 0.], [ 1.], [ 1.], [ 0.], [ 1.], [ 1.], [ 0.], [ 1.], [ 1.], [ 0.], [ 1.], [ 1.], [ 0.], [ 1.], [ 1.], [ 0.], [ 1.], [ 1.], [ 0.], [ 1.], [ 1.], [ 0.], [ 1.], [ 1.], [ 0.], [ 0.], [ 0.], [ 0.], [ 0.], [ 0.], [ 0.], [ 0.], [ 0.]])

    W = np.array([[-4046.], [-4046.], [-4046.], [-4046.], [-4046.], [ 4027.], [ 4027.], [ 4032.], [ 4036.], [ 4035.], [ 4031.], [ 4037.], [ 4033.], [ 4030.], [ 4028.]])



    W, G, h = matrix(W), matrix(G), matrix(h)
    status, solution = glpk.ilp(W, G.T, h, I=set([0,1]))
    print solution
```

Comment: Can you show us the solution. Sadly i don't have glpk enabled in my cvxopt-install and can't check it. Is the ```0.5``` you are mentioning within the first two variables? I doubt that (because you marked them to be in the integer-domain). **You have to mark integer-variables with I (which should be handled as integers); not the domain (bounds should be used for that)** I read your example as: ```Solve, but keep x0 and x1 within integer-domain```. Can this be the problem here? (If you want to restrict all variables to be integers; ```I``` can be omitted as ```I=range(n)``` should be default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just we need to set all variables to be binaries:

```
 status,solution = glpk.ilp(W, G.T, h,B=set(range(len(W))))
```